# Implicit sign up while using SocialAuthenticationFIlter- xml confuguration

Tags: spring, facebook, hibernate, spring-social

I am implementing the spring social (Facebook authentication) with Hibernate, but I am getting the strange problem like user is not getting authenticated successfully.
I have registered the user in my application without using facebook login but 
when I login through facebook then getting redirected to sign up url because useconnection table does not have the data. I am using `SocialAuthenticationFilter`.
How can I create user connection implicitly so that there should be no need of sign up url? Can somebody please help me by providing the implicit sign up xml configuration for `SocialAuthenticationFilter`.